# Vue v-if v-if-else time complexity

Tags: vue.js

I'm doing a project vue and I wanted to know if vue v-if v-else-if time complexity is O(n) or O(1)

I'm using a component in vue like a switch case (takes input and returns html) something like

```html
<div v-if="type === 'A'">
  <!-- HTML Data -->
</div>
<div v-else-if="type === 'B'">
    <!-- HTML Data -->
</div>
<div v-else-if="type === 'C'">
    <!-- HTML Data -->
</div>
<div v-else>
    <!-- HTML Data -->
</div>
```

but with a lot more cases.

Is that the recommended way to do something like this? or should I make a lot of small component and load them dynamically? which is O(1)

And the reason I have this component is that it takes in a string input and returns a custom icon for a data that can be changed, so they have to be loaded dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to create a type/value map and a `computed` property:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data(){
    return{
      type: 'A',
      types: {A:'A',B:'B',C:'C'}
    }
  },
  computed:{
    typeVal(){
      return this.types[this.type];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{typeVal}}
</div>
```

Comment: But what if instead of returning a simple string I want to return a complex HTML data

Comment: Do you mean to load a different component in each case?

Comment: technically yes, but  each case is just a SVG so it seems like an overkill and waste of time to make a component for each SVG v-else-if worked perfect for this case but with a lot of cases i'm starting to worry it's affecting performance, also I'm coming from Angular where there is ngSwitchCase which is exactly what i'm looking for but couldn't find something similar in Vue

Comment: if it's a small ``html`` string, I suggest taking a look at ``v-html``. This way it's set as the vaue in the map instead of the string

Comment: @coder I found this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-switch-case . I have not tried it and it's not official, but it may fit your purpose.

Comment: that package is using `style="display: none;"` to switch between its choices which is fine in my case but would be problematic if the choices were to do heavy computation in the background, But I guess in that case one must seperate them to different components. And about I also thought about `v-html` but it got a bit inconvenient when I needed to add class bindings and so on, thanks anyway

Comment: The usual solution for this case, in my opinion, is using a ``computed`` property as above. Please mark the answer as the solution if you found it helpful. Class bindings can also use ``computed`` properties btw.